# Using gsub/regex to place quotes around names inside string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have tried searching, but cannot find the exact thing I am looking to do. My apologies if I have overlooked it. I am trying to take a long vector of character strings, all with the same general structure, and place them into a data.frame. The structure is as follows:

```
[1]   "rank, team, record"
[2]   "1 Team 22-4"
[3]   "2 Long Team Name 20-6"
```

My initial thought was to use gsub and a regex expression to place /"  around  the team names (ex. /"Long Team Name/") then use read.table to import, but I am running into difficulty coming up with the regex expression to do this. This would allow me to read in the string as  tab delimited string, correct? If there is an easier suggestion, I am all ears.

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to do?  If you've got the data read in as a vector it sounds like you just need to wrap the vector in `data.frame()`

Comment: Use `sub` to replace the first space and the last space with some special character, (say, `"|"`, for example) then use `strsplit` or `tidyr::separate` on that special character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
library(stringi)

x = c("rank, team, record", "1 Team 22-4", "2 Long Team Name 20-6")

res = stri_replace_first_fixed(x, " ", "|")
res = stri_replace_last_fixed(res, " ", "|")

res = stri_split_fixed(res, pattern = "|", simplify = T)
#      [,1]    [,2]             [,3]    
# [1,] "rank," "team,"          "record"
# [2,] "1"     "Team"           "22-4"  
# [3,] "2"     "Long Team Name" "20-6"
```

The result is a matrix, but you could wrap it in `as.data.frame`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!