# replace white space outside quotes

Tags: r, regex

I am working in R. I am trying to import data, some use tab and some use white space between columns. My code looks like this:

```
gsub("[[:blank:]]", ";", 
readLines(paste(PathToRecipes,recipe.files[i],sep="/")))
```

I read the lines of each file, and then `gsub` replaces all white space with a colon. Then, I will put it in a `write.table` and have a new set of files which I can re-import to data frame.

The problem is I get this:

```
"1";6;"medium;(2-1/4\";to;3-1/4\";dia.)";"Potatoes,;boiled,;cooked;without;skin,;flesh,;without;salt";11367
```

When I should get:

```
"1";6;"medium (2-1/4\" to 3-1/4\" dia.)";"Potatoes, boiled, cooked without skin, flesh, without salt";11367
```

There is text within quotes where white space should not be replaced with ";". How can I tell it to avoid quotes?

Comment: Please provide the original string you're applying `gsub` to.

Comment: i am applying gsub to a group of data files, some files columns are separated by tab and some are separated by a space

Comment: the data is similar to the examples in the post- a number, a number, some text, some text, a number

Comment: I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684224/using-gsub-regex-to-place-quotes-around-names-inside-string

Comment: If it's a `txt`/`csv` file, you can read it with `data.table::fread` which can automatically detect how the columns are separated. look at the `sep = "auto" ` argument. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.4/topics/fread

Comment: @DJV the data.table::fread function is the best solution (and I tried a lot of them!). However, there is one problem. Some of the files were saved with rownames, which are numbers that do not have a header. As a result R does not see the first line and uses the first line of data as headers. I tried to ignore the headers and reconstruct it but the files are just too variable. I need the headers to help manipulate the data. I also thought I could use the fact that this column is integers to isolate it but some files have first columns with data that are integers. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I'm following. What do you mean by headers for rownames? rownames that have meaning? Or are you talking about the headers of the columns? you can use the `header`, `col.names` and `check.names` arguments. They can produce default names.

Comment: there was 2 separate issues. columns had headers and R had assigned rows names. the row names did not have a column header which was throwing off headers for the remaining columns. I resolved this by setting header="auto" in fread. this gave the row names column a generic V1 header and aligned the other headers appropriately. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use a PCRE regex with a SKIP-FAIL technique:

```
(*UCP)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qbPuQP/1). Your data seeems to only have paired double quotes, so the above pattern is sufficient. Else, add a bit more to it:

```
(*UCP)(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+
```

**Details**

- `(*UCP)` - make `\s` Unicode aware
- `(?<!\\)` - no `\` immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `(?:\\{2})*` - 0+ sequences of double backslashes
- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of any escape sequence and then zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - omit and skip the current match starting to look for the next match from the current index (where the skipped match ended)
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - matches 1 or more whitespace in any other context.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/Z0tJpw):

```
rx <- '(*UCP)(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+'
x <- c('"1"; 6; "medium (2-1/4\\" to 3-1/4\\" dia.)"; "Potatoes, boiled, cooked without skin, flesh, without salt"; 11367')
cat(gsub(rx, '', x, perl=TRUE))
## => "1";6;"medium (2-1/4\" to 3-1/4\" dia.)";"Potatoes, boiled, cooked without skin, flesh, without salt";11367
```

Answer (score 0):

If the whitespaces within the text that you do not want to be replaced with semicolons are NOT tab characters then you should be able to do what you're currently doing but instead of using `[[:blank:]]` use `\\t` to replace only just the tab characters rather than all white space.

`gsub("\\t", ";",readLines(paste(PathToRecipes,recipe.files[i],sep="/")))`

Comment: that solution works with files that use tab but leaves me with the problem that some files are separated with a space

Comment: Try to use `\\s` instead of `\\t`. `\\s` stands for any whitespace character including space, not the tab character only.